# Multi-column index or multiple indexes for timeseries MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, time-series

I have a MySQL MyISAM table with about 400 million rows of price data (7GB data + 9GB index) with 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ts`,`instrid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

The number of distinct `id`s (I think cardinality is the word) is ~500 and for most time ranges of interest, inside those time ranges, the cardinality of `id` is a lower ~20 (so there are only 20 or so different ids between March 1st and 2nd).

The queries are almost exclusively of the form:

```
select ts, price from prices where ts between {t1} and {t2} and id = {id}.
```

It seems like some index(s) should speed things up.

Would a combined index on `ts` and `id` or separate indexes on `ts` and `id` be better? Some 3rd alternative? I would also appreciate recommendations to where I could learn how to answer this question for myself.

Would another table type (InnoDB?) be more appropriate for my purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for a single combined index on ts, price and id - normally MySQL does two operations, first it finds the row using the index, then it retrieves the row from the database. However if you have all of the data in the index then it will simply grab the data straight from the index without retrieving the row from the database. It's called a "covering index".

On database choice, most people seem to recommend InnoDB for serious use, there's a good comparison [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/)

Comment: Agreed. Make the covering index with the columns in the following order `(ts, id, price)`.

Comment: An interesting solution. I'll try this out and take a look at that article. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know if it will be a problem if this index will not fit in memory?